# Is there an issue with the loop or error-handling in this code?

Tags: python, error-handling, cs50

I'm doing problem set three of cs50p, outdated.

I'm stuck at this part in the code and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

The code:

```py
months = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
]

while True:
    try:
        date = input("Date: ")
        if "/" in date:
            month, day, year = date.split("/")
        elif "," in date:
            monthday, year = date.split(",")
            month, day = monthday.split(" ")
            month = months.index(month) + 1
        if 0 > int(day) <= 31 or 0 > int(month) < 12:
            raise ValueError()
    except (ValueError, NameError, KeyError):
        pass
    else:
        print(f"{year}-{int(month):02}-{int(day):02}")
        break
```

Comment: Show the input you used, the output you got and what you wanted. And sure we can answer it, you've done real work, showed us the script. Its reasonable to ask at this point.

Comment: Why do you think that you are doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition is wrong:

```
        if 0 > int(day) <= 31 or 0 > int(month) < 12:
```

When you chain comparison operators, they're combined with `and`. So

```
0 > int(day) <= 31
```

means "day is less than 0 and less than or equal to 31". Combining those two subconditions, it only raises `ValueError` when it's less than 0.

The correct condition should be:

```
if not (1 <= int(day) <= 31 and 1 <= int(month) <= 12):
    raise ValueError("Invalid day or month")
```